# What class should I use to create http&https requests&connection - iOs

Tags: ios, http, cookies, connection

I'm looking for a class/framework to use in order to create http / https connections and send requests ( and of course recieve answers ) over them.
I also need support for cookies and for sending custom https certificates.

Any suggestions?
Tnx!

Comment: Do you have access to the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The [Foundation Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001091).

There are about a dozen classes that begin `NSURL…`